# How to get Facebook Ads Statistics and display impressions,clicks,spent

Tags: php, facebook, ads

Does any one know how to display Facebook Ads Statistics and display impressions,clicks,spent on to webpage using PHP .

if anyone have any tutorial for displaying this data, please share it.

I tried but not getting success.

Comment: _"I tried but not getting success"_ Include your attempts in your question and what has gone wrong / any errors you are getting from said attempts, SO isn't here to provide tutorials :)

Comment: Its not a tutorial site. If you are a FB advertiser, then you can access Ads Manager. https://www.facebook.com/help/510910008975690/?ref=u2u

Comment: Below error i am geting {
   "error": {
      "message": "An access token is required to request this resource.",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 104
   }
}

Comment: please post relevant code so we can narrow down the problem :-)

Comment: thanks for reply pinkal. but i am using facebook-php-ads-sdk-master for fetching above requirement. but i am not sure how to use it properly for it. if you have any idea please share it

Comment: Does any one know how to display Ad statistics on web page from facebook?